# Capitalize Element Name in XSL

Tags: xslt, string

I am writing a XSL transformation and my source has an element like this - "title". The target xml should contain "Title". Is there a way to capitalize the first letter of a string in XSL?

Comment: why is this a community wiki?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following on from the Johannes said, to create a new element using **xsl:element** you would probably do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(upper-case(substring(name(), 1, 1)), substring(name(), 2))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If your are using XSLT1.0, you won't be able to use the **upper-case** function. Instead, you will have to make-do with the cumbersome **translate** function

```
    <xsl:element name="{concat(translate(substring(name(), 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), substring(name(), 2))}">
```

Comment: `translate` will be very cumbersome for tag names using non-latin characters, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner: use an existing library: FunctX XSLT http://www.xsltfunctions.com/ There's a function capitalize-first() http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_capitalize-first.html

No need to reinvent the wheel in every XSLT, stick the lib somewhere and xsl:include it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to manually use `<xsl:element>` and then something like the following beast:

```
concat(upper-case(substring(name(), 1, 1)), substring(name(), 2))
```

Comment: `upper-case()` is not available before XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Yes, Tim C noted that already. I wasn't aware of it but you can't solve it differently for the general case anyway. Unless you really want to put a few kibibytes into a `translate`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure XLST1 template that creates CamelCase names from ASCII sentences.

```
<xsl:template name="Capitalize">
    <xsl:param name="word" select="''"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(
        translate(substring($word, 1, 1),
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
        translate(substring($word, 2),
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="CamelCase-recursion">
    <xsl:param name="sentence" select="''"/>
    <xsl:if test="$sentence != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="Capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="word" select="substring-before(concat($sentence, ' '), ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="CamelCase-recursion">
            <xsl:with-param name="sentence" select="substring-after($sentence, ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="CamelCase">
    <xsl:param name="sentence" select="''"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="CamelCase-recursion">
        <xsl:with-param name="sentence" select="normalize-space(translate($sentence, &quot;:;,'()_&quot;, ' '))"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```